# Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster - GUI Bug with Dual Screen (minimie, maximise icons)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

Yes Im sure its a bug.
Im reporting the bug for the first time and Im not sure what is needed for someone to fix this.
I settled on ubuntu and I really dont want to go back to Windows but this is really annoying.

Environment:
Desktop PC running Asus Prime Z790M-PLUS-D4
Firmware Version 1205
13th Gen Intel Core i7-13700KF
NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060

I've got two Dell 27" monitors connected running resolution 3840x2160 with Scale 200%
Im adding this as it may play the role but I dont think so.

Monitor 1 - Active Primary
Monitor 2 - extended

Problem:
When I open anything, any browser or anything that I maximise on the primary screen I can only click X and icons minimise and maximise next to the X icon can not be clicked on.
Its like this area is not clickable , totally excluded from interaction.
If I move the window to the extended screen where there is no TOP BAR that shows Date and time, and power icon everything is fine.

This is the case for all types of windows, such as TeamViewer, Firefox, Edge or Chrome browsers, Sublime Text editor, absolutely anything that you can think of.
Once maximised on the active monitor I can not minimise it, I can not do anything other than X it out.
If I move it slighly lower, drag and drop action I can click the icons just fine.

There is another annoyence which would be great if I could have fixed but its less important.
The monitors operate in extended mode.
When computer goes to sleep and I wake it up it comes back as clonning. I have to turn off the screen and turn back on again and it returns to extended.

When I go to settings they all show as extended but its actually cloning.
If I modify anything there it will refresh itself and goes back to extended but the fact that I have to do this everytime its just annoying.

How can we have this addressed any thoughts?

Comment: We can help you determine if you have a bug or something else. And we can help you to write a good bug report. But AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker. You have not really reported a bug yet.

Comment: Start with this: If a developer or bug triager wanted to reproduce this issue using their own test hardware, what steps should they follow? What release of Ubuntu? What additions or changes or customizations should they make from a stock Ubuntu install of that release? Alternately, do your logs have clues about what might be happening?